# Searching JavaScript JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

My PHP is returning the following JSON (2 entries shown, it could be more, but the structure will be the same):

```
{
    "0": {
        "campaign_id": "31",
        "title": "new title",
        "description": "new description",
        "destinations": {}
    },
    "1": {
        "campaign_id": "32",
        "title": "title",
        "description": "description",
        "destinations": {}
    }
}
```

I want to access the `destinations` where `campaign_id` matches a given value. How do I do that?

Comment: Cant you get the jsonArray  from server side instaed of this JSON object?

Comment: How would I do that from PHP, using http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your response to object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

Now you can loop through the JSON:

```
var destinations;
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key].campaign_id == "value") {
       destinations = obj[key].destinations;
       break;
    }
}
console.log(destinations);
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go. Or perhaps change the PHP from `json_encode($campaigns, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` to `json_encode($campaigns);`, which ought to do the same thing(?)

Comment: In fact, I did change the PHP as per my previous comment and then I could loop as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys` and the `filter` to perform matching:

- **[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a *for...in* loop.
- **[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
- **[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

---

```
var obj = {...}; //your data object
var destinations = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
    return obj[key].campaign_id === "32"
}).map(function(key) {
    return obj[key].destinations;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

## Using [`lodash.find`](https://lodash.com/docs#find):

```
var data = ...
var destinations = _.find(data, e => e.campaign_id == 31).destinations;
```

## Pure JS

```
function find(data, predicate, def) {
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && predicate(data[key], key)) {
            return data[key];
        }
    }
    return def;
}

var data = ...
var destinations = find(data, e => e.campaign_id== 31).destinations;
```

## The best solution with dictionaries

In this case it would be the best if the server would actually send an object, where the items themselves are keyed by their `campaign_id`, then it would be just:

```
var data = ...
data[31].destinations
```

Comment: Good, but lodash is not marked as a tag in the question.

Comment: @jherax He might be new to javascript and don't even know lodash exists. I added alternate solutions.